# prevent val inject code

Tags: jquery, input, code-injection

I'm using jQuery to set the value of a variable to the value of an input box, but it looks like .val() is highly vulnerable to injection. I want to escape strings written in the input box before saving them to a variable, and then later output the escaped string to a place somewhere else on the same page.

On a related note, .text() doesn't seem to work with retrieving the value of input boxes. It's something to do with manually editing the text in an input box after it's been placed on the page.

Simple sample code:

```
var $variable = $('#input').val();
```

What's the best way of going about retrieving the value of an input box safely?

Comment: How is `.val()` vulnerable to injection?

Comment: Injection is not an issue of input but of output. So it depends on what you do with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it looks like .val() is highly vulnerable to injection

It isn't remotely vulnerable to injection. None of the data in it gets `eval`ed by the JS engine or parsed as HTML.

Things you later do with the data may introduce a vulnerability, but you need to deal with them then.

> I want to escape strings written in the input box before saving them to a variable

Don't. Escaping should be done Just In Time. i.e. as close to the point of vulnerability as possible. This is because the method you use for escaping depends on which point of vulnerability you are escaping for.

> and then later output the escaped string to a place somewhere else on the same page.

Use `text()` (or `val()` on an `<output>` element) to *output* the string. That will use methods which aren't vulnerable to being parsed as JavaScript or HTML.

Answer (score 1):

`text()` shouldn't work to retrieve the value of an input. It's for retrieving the inner *text* of an element.

`val()` is your friend here; not at all sure why you'd think it was vulnerable to injection. It simply collects the value -- as plain text, without interpretation -- that's been entered in.

By all means, output it later in a way that escapes any HTML that may be found - either by using `text()` to render it as the contents of an element, or `document.createTextNode()` to create safe text to append to an element.